# Фильтр значений django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-3.5, django-admin

В models.py есть 3 таблицы Company(Компании производящие ЦП), Family(Линейки ЦП), CPU(ЦП). Таблицы Family и Company связаны связью один ко многим. Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении новой записи в админке Django, выбрав определенную компанию в таблице CPU, выходили только линейки ЦП этих компаний? Например: если я выберу компанию Intel, у меня появляются в выпадающем списке только i3, i5, i7, i9.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals    
from django.db import models  
# Create your models here.
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Family(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class CPU(models.Model):
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, нет простого способа это сделать. Наверное придется изменять шаблоны и с помощью AJAX фильтровать значения выпадающего списка. Или искать какие-то пакеты, которые эти возможности добавляют.

Comment: А как связаны cpu и family?

Comment: @Александр, если честно я думал Family связать c СPU через поле company, и вставить проверку, например,  если я выберу компанию Intel, у меня появляются в выпадающем списке только i3, i5, i7, i9. Но так и ничего не получилось

Comment: @НеуловимыйДжо  надо family связать с cpu через foreign key-поле внутри cpu

Comment: @Александр `model = models.ForeignKey(Family, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`, в итоге в таблице СPU я могу получить значения из таблицы Family, если быть точнее то это будет поле name. Однако я не могу понять как сделать, так чтобы при выборе компании , у меня в выпадающем списке появлялись только те линейки процессоров которые только ей и принадлежат. На данный момент я могу выбирать только линейки процессоров.

Comment: @НеуловимыйДжо я так понимаю для самих процов помимо фирм и линеек предусмотрен 3й выпадающий список?

Comment: Cpu_list = Family.get(id=1).CPU_set.all()